# ¿Es recomendable crear un objeto e invocar un método sobre ese objeto en una misma linea de código?

Tags: java, poo, objeto, constructor, metodos

soy nuevo en Java
Tenia entendido que para invocar un método de instancia era necesario seguir la siguiente estructura:

```
public class Main{
    public void main(String[] args) {
        //Primero creo el objeto y lo guardo su referencia en una variable
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        //Después uso esa variable para invocar un método, que es como normalmente se hace
        String hoy = sdf.format(new Date());
        System.out.println(hoy);
    }
}
```

Pero recientemente vi que es posible hacer esto:

```
public class Main{
    public void main(String[] args) {
        String hoy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new Date());
        /*
           Aquí estoy creando una instancia e inmediatamente estoy invocando
           un método, sin haber guardado la referencia del objeto
        */
        System.out.println(hoy)
    }
}
```

Y no se presenta ningún problema al ejecutar el código

La diferencia esta que en el segundo código estoy creado un objeto e inmediatamente estoy invocando un método sobe él

Mi pregunta es ¿Realmente es buena practica hacer esto? o por el contrario debe evitarse hacer? Ya que casi nunca he visto que se invoquen métodos de instancia de esta forma.

Comment: No hay problema en hacer eso, y al contrario si tu objeto (sdf en el primer código) no lo vas a usar para nada más, yo hasta lo recomendaría.

Comment: Está pregunta podría considerarse basada en opiniones. En este caso no sé si sea una buena práctica, pero sigue el sentido común. Elige siempre la forma que sea más legible. Tener muchas instrucciones en la misma línea potencialmente hacen el código más difícil de leer. Por cierto, en Java existe lo que se conoce como [Method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103985/13419694). [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) lo permite.

Comment: Sí es recomendable, pero no siempre. Cuando afecte la legibilidad de lo que hace el código es mejor tener pasos intermedios con nombres de variables significativos aunque se usen una sola vez. En este caso concreto no hay problema porque es bastante claro, pero si tuvieras por ejemplo muchas llamadas anidadas como parámetros e invocaciones en cadena, es mejor evitarlo. Con el tiempo ganarás experiencia y sabrás crear código reducido y a la vez legible/mantenible.